# Android Talkback does not read utf-8 characters in the Webview using html

Tags: android, html, utf-8, webview, talkback

I have an info.html for my App which is in a webview. info.html is encoded with UTF-8.

I want talkback to vocalize the text in it however it fails in some non-english characters.

```
String infoURL = "file:///android_asset/info.html";
WebView view  =  (WebView) theAct.findViewById(R.id.webview);
view.loadUrl(infoURL);
```

I used also this, which failed:

```
String infoURL = "file:///android_asset/info.html";
WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
view.loadUrl(infoURL);
```

or:

```
...
view.loadDataWithBaseURL(infoURL, null, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file itself is saved as UTF-8, sometimes is not sufficient to specify

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

inside html file